# how can i wrap this (AdsWizz) Kotlin callback function in a couroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new to coroutines and having a hard time figuring out how to correctly wrap an existing callback in a coroutine.

My goal is to be able to do the following:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val theResult = getPreRollAd()      //1. call this suspending func and wait for result

        doSomethingWithResult(theResult)    //2. now that the result is returned from AdsWizz API (below), do something with it 
    }
}
```

Here is the AdsWizz API call that I'd like to "wrap":

```
val adReqInterface: AdRequestHandlerInterface =  object :
    AdRequestHandlerInterface {

    override fun onResponseError(error: AdswizzSDKError) {
        Timber.e("onResponseError $error")
    }

    override fun onResponseReady(adResponse: AdResponse) {
        Timber.d( "onResponseReadySingleAd")

        //this contains the url to the ad, title, etc..
        !!!*** I WANT TO RETURN THE adResponse.mediaFile?.source string back to "theResult" variable above (in lifecycleScope.launch {.... )


    }
}

try {
    AdswizzSDK.getAdsLoader().requestAd(adReqParams, adReqInterface)

} catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
    Timber.d( "IllegalArgumentException")
} catch (e: SecurityException) {
    Timber.d( "SecurityException")
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Timber.d( "other exception")
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

I've tried using `suspendCoroutine {...` to wrap but nothing is working. Really appreciate someones help re the right way to achieve this.

Comment: `suspendCoroutine` is the right tool, but you said "nothing is working" with it without showing your attempts nor the symptoms. How can we help then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the right way to do it is to use `suspendCancellableCoroutine`. It can return a result or can be cancelled with an exception.

```
suspend fun getPreRollAd(): AdResponse {
return suspendCancellableCoroutine {

    ...

    val adReqInterface: AdRequestHandlerInterface =  object : AdRequestHandlerInterface {

        override fun onResponseError(error: AdswizzSDKError) {
            Timber.e("onResponseError $error")
            it.cancel(error)
        }

        override fun onResponseReady(adResponse: AdResponse) {
            Timber.d( "onResponseReadySingleAd")
            it.resume(adResponse)
        }

    }

    AdswizzSDK.getAdsLoader().requestAd(adReqParams, adReqInterface)
}

}


viewModelScope.launch {
  val result = try {
    getPreRollAd()
  } catch(e: Throwable) {
    null
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: `onResponseError` should call `resumeWithException`, rather than `cancel`.

Comment: I'm not sure but i think it has the same behavior.

Comment: The behavior is completely different, which can be easily checked by reviewing the [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-cancellable-continuation/).

Comment: brilliant @Pierluigi thank you so much !! So simple once you see how it works. really liking coroutines. thanks again.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik i know the documentation, and i know that the internal status of the coroutine is different but what I mean is if there is a difference in this use case?! If there is a difference could you explain it? The only difference that I know is if there wiill be another call to `resume` or `resumeWithException` that in this case i think is impossible.

Comment: `cancel` resumes with the `CancellationException` and not with the exception you provide. That one will the the cause of the `CancellationException`. Furthermore, even in this context cancelling the coroutine is not the desired behavior, but rather signaling the error to the caller.